# How to securely temporarily store a password?

Tags: android, security, encryption, passwords

If building an application where for sending a series of emails the app must temporarily store the user's password, what is the most secure practice of doing this, if any? If not, what would you recommend?

Comment: I don't think there is any. The password must be somewhere in the memory to use, and therefore is vulnerable to some degree. If you are talking about disk storage you could use an encryption algorithm, like AES or Blowfish, and decrypt later.

Comment: What is temporarily? If you store it on internal storage it can stay there forever - you just need to kill the app before it deletes it.

Comment: Can you change the server or is username/password the only available authentification? If you can change the server, use the password once to aquire an access token and use that for authentification for the single mails. The access token can get invalidated from the server-side, while an password can't (without useability impact). Encrypting the password in-memory does not give you much of a benifit as you also need to store the key on the device... also, you can limit the token to only sending mails, thus important other features are secure (changing the password, etc).

Comment: @dst I don't know if that's possible in my case, but definitely food for thought. I know that encryption wouldn't exactly help, but wouldn't it at least make it *slightly* more secure? As any potential threat would also have to hunt for the key in the package? Just wondering, of course, I'm aware it does relatively little in terms of fool proof security.

Comment: If the attacker is able to get your apk (and he is in 99% of the cases), he could just smali it and read through your code. A noob will not be able to access it, but you could as well use a caesar cipher to prevent that...

Comment: There's a basic common sense rule which points to dsts' comments showing to way to go.  "If it's on the phone, it's not secure".  The best you can do is to make the cost of discovering the secret greater than it's value.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not sending the password over the internet, it should not really matter much. If you do want to be more secure, you could store the password in a string and then after it is no longer needed, overwrite it with a string of identical length.

Comment: Why specifically with a string of identical length? Wouldn't assigning the string variable to any string work?

Comment: Storing the password does matter. If the device gets lost is is crucial the theft would get your user's plain-text passwords, as they usually are used on other services by regular users (sad fact), additonally the real user should be able to revoke its authentification without physical access to it.

Comment: My apologies. I believed that by temporarily storing it, he meant storing it in memory, where it would not be persisted. As for overwriting it, you would need a string of greater or equal length. Preferrably, the server would accept a hashed version of the password, and as such you could store that instead of the plaintext.

Comment: @bjc2406 with that definition of temporary I agree, as you don't have a chance to do it differently. As you guessed I read your answer in another way ;)

Comment: On a point of order, overwriting the string in memory will not help since the runtime will create a new string to hold the result of whatever manipulation you do.  Only then will the old string be freed but the memory location will hold the original characters until the memory block is used again - which is entirely indeterminate to the app.

Comment: @Simon I suppose. I'd forgotten that the JVM did that to strings as I've been using C more lately and C has manual memory management

Answer (score 1):

You could use the shared preferences from the device to store and retrieve the password as a string. This string can be deleted from the preferences once you are finished with it.

Comment: Aren't other apps able to access this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of each app has its own directory within the device for storing app data, this shouldn't matter it you are only storing the data for a short time